# assign multible lines into a json dictionary in flask

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, flask

I have a model deployed with flask.i name it

```
hope4.py

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify#--jsonify will return the data
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#creates the web service running on port 127.0.0.1:12345 and answer post requests on address of the machine/api
app = Flask(__name__)


model=load_model('modelfordeploy.h5')

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "machine learning model APIs!"


    @app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def predict():

        # get the json send from the post as data
        data=request.get_json(force=True)
        print (data)

        # i want 6 variables to make the prediction
        #i expected jason to have the following values
        predict_request=[data["accx"], data["accy"], data["accz"], data["gyrx"], data["gyry"], data["gyrz"]]
        print (predict_request)

        predict_request= np.array(predict_request)
        print (predict_request)

        predict_request = np.asarray( predict_request).reshape(-1, 1, 6)

        pred= model.predict(predict_request)
        print (pred)

        output=[pred[::]]
        print (output)

        #take a list of dictionaries and convert them to json
        return jsonify(results=output)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(port=8000, debug=True) #threaded=False)
```

I want to take input from the client and bring back the category to him. More specific my initial model is receiving 1401 windows of data (50hz* 2 sec). I want to send one window of data (100 rows) and take back the prediction. Below is the `request.py`. Do I have to make the changes in `hope4.py` or on the `request.py`?

```
import requests, json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# #with request a make  a json call in the below adress and i post the following

url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"
r = requests.post(url,json={"accx":0.660583, "accy":0.454468, "accz":-0.585022, "gyrx":32.366615, "gyry":27.206556, "gyrz":-23.471800})

print(r.json())
```

my model expects 100 rows and 6 features and not 1 rows and 6 feature. How to send 100 rows without explicitly write by hand like above?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# You can either

r = requests.post(url,
    json=[
        {"accx":0.660583, "accy":0.454468, "accz":-0.585022,
         "gyrx":32.366615, "gyry":27.206556, "gyrz":-23.471800},
        {"accx":0.660583, "accy":0.454468, "accz":-0.585022,
         "gyrx":32.366615, "gyry":27.206556, "gyrz":-23.471800},
        ...
    ])

# Or
r = requests.post(url,
    json={
        "accx": [0.660583, ...],
        "accy": [0.454468, ...],
        "accz": [-0.585022, ...],
        "gyrx": [32.366615, ...],
        "gyry": [27.206556, ...],
        "gyrz": [-23.471800, ...]},
    ])
```

Comment: thank yoy Dimitri K.Sifoua. is there a way to send automatically 100 rows from the dataframe?

Comment: Yes you can! With the function `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)